# How is this recursive CodeQL predicate is evaluated?

Tags: recursion, codeql

I'm in the process of trying to learn CodeQL and I'm a little confused about how certain CodeQL code is evaluated. I'm hoping someone can help me with a more simplistic explanation.

Take the following CodeQL code:

```
string getANeighbor(string country){
  country = "France" and result = "Belgium"
  or
  country = "France" and result = "Germany"
  or
  country = "Germany" and result = "Austria"
  or
  country = "Germany" and result = "Belgium"
  or
  country = getANeighbor(result)
}

select getANeighbor("Germany")
```

The result I get back is:

```
France
Austria
Belgium
```

I understand why Belgium and Austria are returned. However I'm confused as to how CodeQL determines that France is to be returned as a result. My imperative programming intuition tells me that for France to be returned, I would need an additional line that looks something like *country = "Germany" and result = "France"*, but I'm really confused here how France is being returned without that line of code.

Also, how does this line work exactly?:

```
country = getANeighbor(result)
```

With some of the simple examples that are given in the CodeQL handbook, they make it seem like that the '*result*' keyword almost acts like 'return' in other languages. I feel that I have a fundamental misunderstanding of what '*result*' does and how it works. I can't seem to find a good explanation after googling.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the question from a a user who was kind enough to answer my question at a different site. 
Source (https://github.com/github/securitylab/discussions/85):

Answer (Provided by: Pavel Avgustinov from Semmle):

> This is a great question. I'll give the full details on recursive
>   predicates below, but let's first deal with `result`.
>
> ---
>
> *Also, how does this line work exactly?:*
>
> *`country = getANeighbor(result)`*
>
> *With some of the simple examples that are given in the CodeQL handbook, they make it seem like that the 'result' keyword almost acts
>   like 'return' in other languages. I feel that I have a fundamental
>   misunderstanding of what 'result' does and how it works. I can't seem
>   to find a good explanation after googling.*
>
> ---
>
> You're right to observe that in many examples `result = f()` in CodeQL
>   seems to act like `return f()` in other languages. However, a `return`
>   statement (with its usual meaning of actually interrupting the
>   evaluation of a function and returning to the caller) does not make
>   sense in a logic language, where it's up to the CodeQL evaluator how
>   and in what order to evaluate the different parts of a predicate you
>   define. Instead, when a predicate declares a return type (`string` in
>   your example), this implicitly declares the special variable `result`
>   in its body, whose type is the declared return type of the predicate.
>   You can use this variable just like any other, in particular to
>   constrain it as part of the predicate.
>
> Note that `this` is quite similar to how you implicitly get a special
>   variable called this in a member predicate (or method, in traditional
>   languages).
>
> Other than its implicit declaration, there is nothing special about
>   the `result` variable. In particular, logically you could write the
>   `getANeighbor` predicate like this, without its use:
>
> ```
> predicate getANeighbor(string country, string neighbor) {   
> country = "France" and neighbor = "Belgium"
> or
> country = "France" and neighbor = "Germany" 
> or
> country = "Germany" and neighbor = "Austria" 
> or 
> country = "Germany" and neighbor = "Belgium" 
> or  
> getANeighbor(neighbor, country)
> }
> ```
>
> You do have to invoke the predicate differently if you declare it
>   without a result type: `getANeighbor(neighbor, country)` rather than
>   `country = getANeighbor(result)`. Other than this syntactic detail,
>   the two are entirely equivalent.
>
> If you get used to the idea that `result` is just an implicitly
>   declared variable, not some special way of signaling the returned
>   value of a predicate, then code like `country = getANeighbor(result)`
>   (or more complex cases, where `result` is used multiple times to place
>   multiple conditions on it) will make more sense. Contrast it to the
>   `result`-free version I gave above, which explicitly flips the order
>   of arguments in the recursive call to `getANeighbor`: it's exactly the
>   same thing, we're invoking `getANeighbor` with "flipped" arguments,
>   namely `result` as the first parameter, and `country` equated to the
>   "returned" value.
>
> As a final observation, you can of course get something more similar
>   to the `return`-like style of many examples by introducing an
>   intermediate variable: Instead of `country = getANeighbor(result)`, we
>   can write `exists(string neighbor | country = getANeighbor(neighbor) and result = neighbor)`, but you can see how this ends up being more
>   verbose.
>
> ---
>
> The general intuition behind recursion in CodeQL is given [here](https://help.semmle.com/QL/ql-handbook/recursion.html),
>   but at a high level you can think of each recursive call as
>   representing the "current" set of value tuples in the called
>   predicate, and all predicate definitions keep being evaluated until
>   there is no change. Let's see how this works in your example
>   predicate:
>
> ```
> string getANeighbor(string country)
> {   
> country = "France" and result = "Belgium"   
> or
> country = "France" and result = "Germany"
> or
> country = "Germany" and result = "Austria"
> or
> country = "Germany" and result = "Belgium"
> or
> country = getANeighbor(result) 
> }
> ```
>
> The first time we try to evaluate `getANeighbour`, we do not know
>   anything about it, and so we treat a call to it as a call to the empty
>   set of values. This means we deduce the following values for it:
>
> ```
> +-----------+----------+---------+
> | iteration | country  | result  |
> +-----------+----------+---------+
> |    1      | France   | Belgium |
> |    1      | France   | Germany |
> |    1      | Germany  | Austria |
> |    1      | Germany  | Belgium |
> +-----------+----------+---------+
> ```
>
> However, after deducing these values, we know that there was a
>   recursive call to `getANeighbor`, and that the values we have for it
>   changed. Thus, we need to re-evaluate the definition of
>   `getANeighbor`, now using our expanded set of values for the recursive
>   call. This means that we deduce the following:
>
> ```
> +-----------+----------+---------+
> | iteration | country  | result  |
> +-----------+----------+---------+
> |    2      | France   | Belgium |
> |    2      | France   | Germany |
> |    2      | Germany  | Austria |
> |    2      | Germany  | Belgium |
> |           |          |         |
> |    2      | Belgium  | France  |
> |    2      | Germany  | France  |
> |    2      | Austria  | Germany |
> |    2      | Belgium  | Germany |
> +-----------+----------+---------+
> ```
>
> Note that we re-deduced the first four lines, which do not depend on a
>   recursive call, just like we did in iteration 1. This is fine -- we
>   already knew that `"Belgium" = getANeighbor("France")` was true, and
>   thus we can simply ignore the fact that we deduced it in another way.
>   However, the last four lines are new; they arise from the recursive
>   call.
>
> As before, we see that iteration 2 of evaluating `getANeighbor`
>   depended on a recursive predicate for which we have deduced new
>   values, and so we need to go around again. In the third iteration, we
>   deduce:
>
> - (a) the first four lines of iteration 2 (and iteration 1), just like before, from the non-recursive parts of the predicate definition;
> - (b) the last four lines of iteration 2, in the same way as for iteration 2 itself; and
> - (c) all 8 lines from iteration 2, just by applying the recursive case to the results of iteration 2. However, we didn't deduce any
>     *new* values, and so we know that at this point we can stop evaluation of `getANeighbor`. We say that it has "converged" (meaning "stopped
>     changing"), and for any other references to it, we are going to use
>     the final set of values which we computed.
>
> This is why in your query, `France` is reported as a neighbor of
>   `Germany`.
>
> [I've omitted some details of how to make such a recursive evaluation
>   efficient -- in practice there are some ways to avoid re-deducing the
>   same values again and again on each recursive iteration --, because
>   they are not necessary to understand how recursion works in the first
>   place.]

Thanks again to Pavel Avgustinov from Semmle for this detailed response!